# TextView android:gravity set to center_horizontal not working correctly when drawn to a bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, textview, gravity

IMPORTANT:
I want to draw content of a View A to a bitmap and part of the View A is a TextView which text has to be centered horizontally. The View A is not displayed nor is part of another View.

QUESTION:
How can I tell the TextView to display the text correctly when it is drawn to a bitmap????

My base layout(base_layout.xml):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shiftsListTV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:padding="3dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My TestActivity.java activity, which I use for testing:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout mainHolderLL;

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutXml() {
        return R.layout.activity_test;
    }

    @Override
    protected final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mainHolderLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainHolderLL);

        View baseLayoutView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.base_layout, null);

                dateTV.setText("Feb 2014");
                shiftsListTV.setText("shift1, shift2");
        int width = 500;
        int height = 500;

        int widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

        baseLayoutView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);        
        baseLayoutView.layout(0, 0, baseLayoutView.getMeasuredWidth(), baseLayoutView.getMeasuredHeight());

                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(baseLayoutView.getMeasuredWidth(),                                  baseLayoutView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);       
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);     
                baseLayoutView.draw(canvas);

                ImageView appwidget_image_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.appwidget_image_view);       
        appwidget_image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

activity_test.xml:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainHolderLL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/common_padding_normal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/appwidget_image_view"
                android:layout_width="294dp"
                android:layout_height="294dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

If the bitmap is displayed inside a ImageView, the text inside dateTV TextView is not centered horizontally and it looks as crushed(on Android 4.3 but on Android 2.3.3 nothing is displayed), but the text inside shiftsListTV is displayed correctly.

If I remove the `android:gravity` attribute from dateTv TextView the text inside dateTV is displayed correctly but is not centered. I need the text centered.

Edit:

After some research I found out that TextView has a problem with gravity tag.

The imageview is NOT important it is solely for displaying the bitmap.

Comment: You haven't posted your whole layout - where is the ImageView? Which View is `view` (the one upon which you call `draw(canvas)`)?

Comment: See my edits and also I edited my whole question

Comment: "When I display the imageview, the text in the textview is not centred horizontally" - please re-ask your question.

Comment: I have re-formulated my question and provided better explanation of what I want to achieve...Can you help me please?

Comment: the first odd thing I see is the circular dependency on layout_height - the text views both match parent but the parent is wrap content. "developer options - show layout bounds" will be your friend when debugging this.

Comment: I have changed the base_layout.xml file...Have you tested my code to see the result?

Comment: No, have you tested it?

Comment: Yes I have tested it...Please test my code to see the result